# Did the voice of actor of Freezer worked in Gintama?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, gintama

I'm watching the Gintama 2006 anime series and there is an anime character in episode 13 which its voice sounds a lot like Freezer from Dragon Ball. Did the voice of actor of Freezer worked in Gintama?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%B0%BE%E9%9A%86%E8%81%96), yes, and the character's name was Daraku.